# How to override or extend proceed-to-checkout.js

Tags: checkout, javascript, mixins

I need to override or extend Magento's `proceed-to-checkout.js` file in my module.
[app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js)

In my modules requirejs-config.js I have tried using a mixin and also replacing the mapping with both...

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout': {
                'Mynamespace_Checkout/js/view/proceed-to-checkout-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

AND

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            proceedToCheckout: 'Mynamespace_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout'
        }
    }
};
```

Neither work and I'm unsure how I should write the mixin as Magento's original [proceed-to-checkout.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js) file simply returns an anonymous function with a jQuery click event listener.

Any idea how I can get this to work in a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout": 'SR_MagentoCommunity/js/proceed-to-checkout'
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config, element) {
        console.log('new');
        $(element).click(function (event) {
            var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
                customer = customerData.get('customer');

            event.preventDefault();

            if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
                authenticationPopup.showModal();

                return false;
            }
            $(element).attr('disabled', true);
            location.href = config.checkoutUrl;
        });

    };
});
```

Clear static content if you are not in developer mode.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found a solution with a mixin and without having to override the original code in case you want to add something to the element onclick:

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData) {
    return function (target) {
        return function (config, element) {
        var result = target(config, element);

        $(element).on('click', function (event) {
            //Your code here
        });

        return result;
    };
};
});
```

Hope this might help